# Export All Views to Text File using Pg Admin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a way I can use the system catalog (information schema maybe?) to export the `CREATE VIEW` script for all of the views?

Something like this in the output:

```
CREATE VIEW PUBLIC.EXAMPLE_VIEW AS
...
```

Comment: `select table_name, view_definition from information_schema.views where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');`

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I output the file, the definition spills over to the table name and messed everything up when I import the file into Excel.

Comment: That is a formatting issue in Excel, pretty sure that can be fixed by widening the column width in Excel.

Comment: part of the code will go on cell D1 and the rest will go to cell A2. That's not widening, that's something else, but not sure what else.

Answer (score 2):

This will output the definitions of all views that are neither system views nor belong to an extension:

```
SELECT format('CREATE VIEW %I AS ', v.oid::regclass)
       || pg_get_viewdef(v.oid)
FROM pg_class AS v
WHERE v.relkind = 'v'
  AND v.relnamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
                             'information_schema'::regnamespace)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_depend
                  WHERE deptype = 'e'
                    AND classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
                    AND objid = v.oid);
```

Comment: I added 2 columns, one for the database name and 1 for the schema name. When I import into Excel, it puts part of the code under the object definition and part under the column for the database. Maybe this is a newline feed or carriage return problem?

Comment: That is probably a question of how you export the query results. Use `COPY` to generate a CSV file; even Microsoft should be able to cope with that.